# A potential supervisor didn't respond to my email. It's been a week, does this mean he's not interested?

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor, email

A week ago I contacted a potential supervisor with shared interests. He answered back on the same day, positively reflecting his will to cooperate and support my application. I replied to him on the second day with a draft of the aimed project. It has been a week since that email and there has been no answer or reply. Should I assume that he is no longer interested?! Or should I wait a bit longer?!

Comment: See [What does it mean if a professor does not answer your email in time?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24285/what-does-it-mean-if-a-professor-does-not-answer-your-email-in-time), [What to do when emails to a potential advisor are not replied?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9644/what-to-do-when-emails-to-a-potential-advisor-are-not-replied), [Is ignoring emails acceptable in academia?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/is-ignoring-emails-acceptable-in-academia), etc.

Comment: IMO, a week is very short. Please be patient. Ask this question if you have not heard from him after a month.

Comment: I am worried because the application deadline is by the end of next week !

Comment: I hope you have profusely applogised for contacting him so close to the deadline,

Comment: IMO, your application and the reply from the prof should be separate. You can go ahead send the application and waiting for his reply at the same time.

Comment: He said he is interested in supporting the application but didn't answer back yet! Shall I resend him an email?

Comment: I would send a brief reminder.

Comment: shall I say : " Would You kindly acknowledge your receipt of the sent email ?!" Or another way ?!